# Login PHP script Username and password is correct, but won't login

Tags: php, authentication

I had to fix some errors with my PHP Login script, That when a user have made a account with a Uppercase letter, it won't let him login with all lowercase, So I decided to fix that, However, It won't log in, It just redirects to the login with my message "Unexpected error occurred".

It goes through the Username check, but not the password, And it does not return password is incorrect.

I tried to make a new account, And it still goes to that error page, But this time, It actually logged me in, but not with the You have successfully logged in, and the existing users can't login, But the new one I made did.

And I did try a password reset, It works, But doesn't lead to Success login message.

The other change I did was to the Hashing of Password, As I use username Password Salt, And I changed from `$hash = hash('sha256',$Username.$Password.$Salt);` to `$hash = hash('sha256',strtolower($Username).$Password.$Salt);` because, when the Username was uppercase or lowercase, It had effects on the Password check.

My code:

```
<?php
    /* Mysql data */
    $MysqlUsername = "root";
    $MysqlPassword = "*********";
    $MysqlHostname = "localhost";
    $MysqlDatabase = "teamgamersnet";
    $Salt = "******";
    $Username = $_POST['Username'];
    $Password = $_POST['Password'];
    $Remember = $_POST['Remember'];
    $Cookie = "TGN";
    $IP       = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    if (empty($Username) || empty($Password)) { die("Please fill in all the fields"); }


    $hash = hash('sha256',strtolower($Username).$Password.$Salt);

    $Sql = new mysqli($MysqlHostname, $MysqlUsername, $MysqlPassword, $MysqlDatabase);
    if ($Sql->connect_error){ echo $Sql->connect_error; }
    $sUser = $Sql->real_escape_string($Username);
    $sPass = $Sql->real_escape_string($Password);
    $xPass = $Sql->real_escape_string($hash);


    $CheckUser = $Sql->query("SELECT Username FROM `users` WHERE `Username` = '".$sUser."'");
    $CheckPass = $Sql->query("SELECT Password FROM `users` WHERE `Username` = '".$sUser."'");
    $CheckActive = $Sql->query("SELECT Activated FROM `users` WHERE `Username` = '".$sUser."'");
    if ($CheckUser->num_rows == 0) { header("Location: /?p=Login&wrongusr=true"); die(); }
    $xCheckUser = $CheckUser->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $xCheckPass = $CheckPass->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $xCheckAct =  $CheckActive->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    if ($xCheckAct['Activated'] == "false") { header("Location: /?p=Login&activate=true"); die(); }
    if(strtolower($Username) == strtolower($xCheckUser['Username'])) { // Check if username match
        if($hash == $xCheckPass['Password']) { // Check if password is correct
        if(isset($Remember)){
                setcookie ($Cookie."User", htmlspecialchars($Username));
                setcookie ($Cookie."Pass", $hash);
        }
        else
        {
                setcookie ($Cookie."User", htmlspecialchars($Username), time() + 3600);
                setcookie ($Cookie."Pass", $hash, time() + 3600);
        }
                header("Location: /?login=true"); // Send them to home page 
    }

    else
    {
        header("Location: /?p=Login&wrongpwd=true"); // Send them to home page 
    }
    header("Location: /?p=Login&unxer=true"); // Username error, Idk why
    }
?>
```

Comment: Instead of using cookies like this, you should check into [Sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)

Comment: @lucianie The error is that when you login, It logs you inn, but it redirects to the login page with the error "A unexepted error occured, try again.." i set, and not to home page with success login.

Comment: Have you tried to `var_dump(strtolower($Username))` and `var_dump(strtolower($xCheckUser["Username"]))` to see why they're not equal? Also, why would you do 3 queries instead of just one? `SELECT Username, Password, Activated` instead?

Comment: $CheckUser = $Sql->query("SELECT Username FROM `users` WHERE `Username` = '".$sUser."'"); is absolutelly not neccesarry, and you can take password and check if activated(or pick activated status if you want) in same query. So, everything you do in 3 queries you should do in one. This is very bad usage of mysql and because code is unnecessary complicated then it is also harder to debug. Also, are you sure Activated field is string? It seams to me that is logic to be bool

Comment: @icrew The Activated field is a string, And yeah, I should just use one query instead of 3 queryes.

Comment: @Teknikk You should use a `tinyint` with length 1 instead of a string, when you want to use booleans.

Comment: I suggest you use print_r or var_export critic variables after every line of code to see where is the error. Or debug it with xdebug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default character set and collation are `latin1` and `latin1_swedish_ci`, so nonbinary string comparisons are case insensitive by default. This means that if you search with `col_name LIKE 'a%'`, you get all column values that start with `A` or `a`.

To make this search case sensitive, make sure that one of the operands has a case sensitive or binary collation. For example, if you are comparing a column and a string that both have the `latin1` character set, you can use the `COLLATE` operator to cause either operand to have the `latin1_general_cs` or `latin1_bin` collation.

You just need to change your `Username` and `Password` fields' collations with `latin1_general_cs` or `latin1_bin`, and then it will work accordingly.